# Javascript MomentJs wrong output

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

**1.**

Ok, for the first question I have a question about Moment. It doesn't calculate the time right(I think?)
This is my script:

```
function CalculateTime() {
    try {
        var originalStartTime = $('#startTime').val(),
            originalEndTime   = $('#endTime').val(),
            originalBreakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

        // breaking hours and minutes. needed format: HH:mm
        var startHours   = originalStartTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
            startMinutes = originalStartTime.substring(3, 5),
            endHours     = originalEndTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
            endMinutes   = originalEndTime.substring(3, 5);

        // momentJs variables
        var mStart = moment().hour(startHours).minute(startMinutes),
            mEnd = moment().hour(endHours).minute(endMinutes),
            mBreak = moment.duration(originalBreakTime);


        var result = moment( mEnd - mStart - mBreak).format('HH:mm');

        $('#workedHours').val(result + " timmar");

    } catch (err) {
        $('#workedHours').val(err);
    }
```

**startTime:** 07:00, **endTime:** 16:00, **breakTime** 00.00
That will result with **workedHours** being 10.00.
This is from the chrome console:
[image]

Comment: .Hours is not a function. TypeError: moment.hours is not a function

Comment: Sorry : `moment().hours( mEnd - mStart - mBreak).hours()` * my mistake!

Comment: Than it just shows 00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [subtract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) method

```js
function CalculateTime() {
  try {
    var originalStartTime = $('#startTime').val(),
      originalEndTime = $('#endTime').val(),
      originalBreakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

    // breaking hours and minutes. needed format: HH:mm
    var startHours = originalStartTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
      startMinutes = originalStartTime.substring(3, 5),
      endHours = originalEndTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
      endMinutes = originalEndTime.substring(3, 5),
      breakHours = originalBreakTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
      breakMinutes = originalBreakTime.substring(3, 5);

    // momentJs variables
    var mStart = moment().hour(startHours).minute(startMinutes),
      mEnd = moment().hour(endHours).minute(endMinutes),
      mBreak = moment.duration(breakHours * 60 + +breakMinutes, 'minutes');

    var result = mEnd.subtract(mStart).subtract(mBreak).format('HH:mm');

    $('#workedHours').val(result + " timmar");

  } catch (err) {
    $('#workedHours').val(err);
  }
}

CalculateTime();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="startTime" value="07:00" />
<input id="endTime" value="16:00" />
<input id="breakTime" value="00.30" />
<input id="workedHours" />
```

---

I think a more momentjs way is

```js
function CalculateTime() {
  try {
    var originalStartTime = $('#startTime').val(),
      originalEndTime = $('#endTime').val(),
      originalBreakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

    // momentJs variables
    var mStart = moment(originalStartTime, 'HH:mm'),
      mEnd = moment(originalEndTime, 'HH:mm'),
      mBreak = moment.duration(originalBreakTime);

    var result = mEnd.subtract(mStart).subtract(mBreak).format('HH:mm');

    $('#workedHours').val(result + " timmar");

  } catch (err) {
    $('#workedHours').val(err);
  }
}

CalculateTime();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="startTime" value="07:00" />
<input id="endTime" value="16:00" />
<input id="breakTime" value="00:30" />
<input id="workedHours" />
```