# Update Javascript after value change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have a project that calculates `startTime`, `EndTime` - `breakTime`.
and displays that into a `WorkedHours` Field.

Like this:
[image]

I have a time picker to choose the time, but my calculate script dosen't run after I changed the value. It runs when I step into the text box.
So if I were to change it like this:
[image]

It will not updated **`Tid Jobbad`** Until I step into that same textbox again. How do I make it call the function each time the value changes?

This is the script:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#breakTime,#startTime,#endTime')
      .blur(CalculateTime);
    CalculateTime();
});


function CalculateTime() {
    try {
        var originalStartTime = $('#startTime').val(),
          originalEndTime = $('#endTime').val(),
          originalBreakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

        // breaking hours and minutes. needed format: HH:mm
        var startHours = originalStartTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
          startMinutes = originalStartTime.substring(3, 5),
          endHours = originalEndTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
          endMinutes = originalEndTime.substring(3, 5);

        // momentJs variables
        var mStart = moment().hour(startHours).minute(startMinutes),
          mEnd = moment().hour(endHours).minute(endMinutes),
          mBreak = moment.duration(originalBreakTime);

        var result = mEnd.subtract(mStart).subtract(mBreak).format('HH:mm');

        $('#workedHours').val(result);

    } catch (err) {
        $('#workedHours').val(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: Any relation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498475/javascript-momentjs-wrong-output/32498746#32498746

Comment: If you want to check if an input value has changed, you can use change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y're using `blur` event and it is sent to an element when it loses focus. So if you want to recalculate values on `change`, you need to bind `onChange` javascript event:

```js
$('#breakTime, #startTime, #endTime').change(CalculateTime);
```